# How to read hdfs file using webhdfs from a secure node?

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, webhdfs

I would like to make a webhdfs call to retrive a file from secure node using Java.

Here is what I am doing
1. login using keytab (works fine). I am getting a kerberos ticket
2. Now when I try to invoke the below code, what it does is, it tries to get the delegationtoken by making a https call and it fails with 401
https://mynode:50070/webhdfs/v1/?op=GETDELEGATIONTOKEN&user.name=myuser

Here is the code to open the hdfs file
FileSystem webFS = FileSystem.get(new URI("swebhdfs://" + domain + "myfile"), conf);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webFS.open(new Path("swebhdfs://" + domain + "myfile"))));

My question is since I have the kerberos ticket, how can I pass that one to UserGropupInformation object?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have access to `keytab` file. 
Add the following snippet before you connect to hadoop cluster.
The `loginUserFromKeytab` method will load and authenticate with the `keytab` for the specified user. ('logs in' in simple terms)

```
String user = "USER@REALM"
String keyPath = "somekeytab.keytab"
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(user, keyPath)
```

`UserGroupInformation` is located in `hadoop-common` jar.

Reference :

[Authenticating Kerberos Principals in Java Code](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_sg_princ_auth_java.html)